# How to solve media plugins erroe in fedora 19?

Tags: media-queries

While installing plugins i get failed to install message often,and from terminal it's saying that /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-rpmfusion-free-fedora-19 file not found.So how to get this file ?

Answer (score 0):

What I understand by what I've read is that each package in RPM Fusion has associated a GPG Signature such that, before the package is installed, yum verifies. This is to check integrity of the package. 
                      Yum verifies the gpg key or each package before installing it. So to get the key file for rpm fusion use link given below and download it and place it in a appropriate path:
http://rpmfusion.org/keys